# Fragments in Froyo

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-2.2-froyo

Can i use Fragments in 2.2 version of the Android (Froyo) using the compatibility package ?

I want to use two nested Tabs which on clicking should display related content in the Fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Short description from their website:

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.

With one API you can use all that 3.0 stuff on pre-3.0 devices. (It looks the same and behaves the same)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Tabs are not supported in the `ActionBar` by the compatibility library.

Comment: thanks you. nice to see u online. not sure if u remember we said hi at droidcon in bangalore